# Perl - Data URI to File::Temp

Tags: perl, pdf, temporary-files, data-uri

I have a Data URI string, for example:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,ABCDEFBLAHBLAH=
```

How do I convert this to a `File::Temp` object?

I've tried taking the string after the first comma and using `Mime::Base64` to decode that string, then printing the decoded string to a new `Temp::File` handler. It works fine for images, but not for PDFs as it believes the file is corrupted (weirdly, Chrome has no problem reading the PDF, but adobe reader, preview, and firefox all claim it's corrupt).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does `file output.pdf` parse the output file as? what does it suggest it is?

Comment: adobe reader, preview and firefox recognise it's a pdf, but when trying to open it, I get errors like 'There was an error opening this document, the file is damaged and could not be repaired'.

Comment: Does the `file` command suggest it is a PDF? (I have a feeling it might actually be a `.jpg` or `.bmp` instead...)

Comment: I think you need to show a specific example which is not working and the code you use to parse it. I could imagine that there is some junk at the end of the output which gets ignored by some PDF readers but not by others.

Comment: What do you mean by 'file command'?

Comment: @Jordan unix has a command, called `file`, which tells you what type of file passed to it is (it looks at the file for specific "magic cookies", identifiers that define what data type the file is). For example: `file output.pdf` gives `output.pdf: JPEG image data, EXIF standard`.

Comment: Are you working on Windows? You should use `binmode` on the file handle before you print to it.